# Conditional segue depending on return value of function

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

My parent viewcontroller has two secondary viewcontrollers (CriteriaViewController and MatchCenterViewController) that it can segue to.

What I want to do is to have it segue to MatchCenter if the "eBayCategorySearch" cloudcode function returns a value of "1", and to CriteriaView if it returns a value of "0".

I've attempted to set something up that does this, but it isn't functioning properly. How can I programatically setup this segue?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;

    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {

                                        if (!error) {

                                            NSLog(@"The result is '%@'", result);

                                            if ([result intValue] == 1) {

                                                [self presentModalViewController:MatchCenterViewController
                                                                        animated:YES];
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                [self presentModalViewController:CriteriaViewController
                                                                        animated:YES];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, the logic to determine which controller to segue to shouldn't be in prepareForSegue -- at the point that's called, the segue is already determined. The code should be wherever you get that result back from your function, and then you should use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: to execute the segue, not use presentModalViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a first comment you shouldn't determine a segue in `prepareForSegue` because it already determined there.

You can create an `IBAction` for your nextButton and determine segue in it

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            NSLog(@"The result is '%@'", result);

                                            if ([result intValue] == 1) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                            } else {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

Now you should connect your next button with this action and set identifiers for your segues in IB.

Also you can use `prepareForSegue` to transfer data between you view controllers

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue"]) {
        MYMatchCenterViewController *matchCenterViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        matchCenterViewController.data = self.someData;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I correctly connect my next button to this? I tried naming the method `- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender`, because I connected the button like so: 

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;`

and ctrl dragged from the viewcontroller icon to both views. Next button doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: You should connect an `IBAction` not `IBOutlet` to your button, see more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingAction.html